# Having issues with moving div

Tags: dynamic

I am trying to create a 300px by 300 px div box that moves with mouse. The only thing is when the visitor click on div it disappear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> if((document.getElementById) && window.addEventListener ||
>   window.attachEvent){  (function(){        var hairCol = "#ff0000";
>
> ```
>   var d = document;       var my = -10;       var mx = -10;       var r;      var
> ```
>
> vert = "";
>
> ```
>   var idx = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
>
>   var thehairs = "<div id='theiframe' scrolling='no'
> ```
>
> style='position:absolute;width:53px;height:23px;overflow:hidden;border:0;opacity:"
>   + opacity +";filter:alpha(opacity=" + opacity * 100+ ");'>dsdsds";      document.write(thehairs);       var like =
>   document.getElementById("theiframe");
>         document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(like);
>
> ```
>   var pix = "px";         var domWw = (typeof window.innerWidth ==
> ```
>
> "number");        var domSy = (typeof window.pageYOffset == "number");
>
> ```
>   if (domWw)          r = window;         else{           if (d.documentElement &&
> ```
>
> typeof d.documentElement.clientWidth == "number" &&
>   d.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
>                 r = d.documentElement;          else{
>                 if (d.body && typeof d.body.clientWidth == "number")
>                     r = d.body;             }       }
>
> ```
>           if(time != 0){          setTimeout(function(){
>                   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(like);
>
>                   if (window.addEventListener){
>                       document.removeEventListener("mousemove",mouse,false);
>                   }  
>                   else if (window.attachEvent){
>                       document.detachEvent("onmousemove",mouse);
>                   }
>               }, time);       }
>
>   function scrl(yx){          var y,x;            if (domSy){
>           y = r.pageYOffset;
>           x = r.pageXOffset;          }           else{
>           y = r.scrollTop;
>           x = r.scrollLeft;           }           return (yx == 0) ? y:x;         }
>
>   function mouse(e){          var msy = (domSy)?window.pageYOffset:0;             if
> ```
>
> (!e)
>                 e = window.event;               if (typeof e.pageY == 'number'){
>                 my = e.pageY - 5 - msy;
>                 mx = e.pageX - 4;           }           else{
>                 my = e.clientY - 6 - msy;
>                 mx = e.clientX - 6;             }           vert.top = my + scrl(0) + pix;          vert.left = mx + pix;       }
>
> ```
>   function ani(){             vert.top = my + scrl(0) + pix;          setTimeout(ani,
> ```
>
> 300);         }
>
> ```
>   function init(){            vert =
> ```
>
> document.getElementById("theiframe").style;           ani();      }       if
>   (window.addEventListener){
>             window.addEventListener("load",init,false);
>             document.addEventListener("mousemove",mouse,false);         }           else if
>   (window.attachEvent){             window.attachEvent("onload",init);
>             document.attachEvent("onmousemove",mouse);      }
>
> })();

}//End.

Comment: Remove the `el.onclick = function(){ this.style.display = 'none'; };` from your scripts.

Comment: Assuming there is a line like that... We can only make wild guesses when you show us none of your code!

Comment: As i said i have no code i m trying to make this div but i dont know how

Comment: You didn't say that you have no code, but in that case, you should try it and come up with some code for it and if it doesn't work then ask here with the specific problem and show us the code you've written so far.